# Android Bring Fragment to top without closing other fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hey I'm working with fragments and I'm able to add a fragment and add it to backstack what I would like is if a fragment is already added. The fragment should be removed from its position in the backstack and brought to the top without closing the other fragments.
 Here is my current code

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack, int transition,int layoutResourceID, FragmentManager fm, String tag){
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    if(fm.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {          
        ft.replace(layoutResourceID, fragment, tag);
        Log.d(TAG, " boolean fragment  Added ");
        ft.setTransition(transition);
        if (addToBackStack)
            ft.addToBackStack(tag);
        ft.commit();
    }else{           
        boolean fragmentPopped = fm.popBackStackImmediate(tag,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        //ft.attach(fragment).commit();

    }          
}
```

Comment: Besides Add/Replace you can also use Hide/Show.

Answer (score 0):

mybe your problem solve by adding this:

```
ft.remove(CurrentFragment.this);
```